# In which order SWT shell and its children are disposed?

Tags: java, shell, swt, dispose

I am making my first tries in Java SWT programming and have a question regarding shells and their children.

I am using [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/implementsgeneralEventListener.htm). In the `handleEvent` method, I am listening for `SWT.Dispose`. But if I dispose a dialog, is this dispose event intercepted before it is passed to the shells children?

I checked in the `handleEvent` method, if the shell and its children are disposed but none of them was. I am confused about if the shell is disposed after when the code in the `handleEvent` method is passed? And are the children disposed firstly? Or the parent shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a control is disposed the `SWT.Dispose` event is sent first.

For controls with children the children are disposed next.

Finally the control's resources are released and the control is marked as disposed.

Comment: You mean, the parent shell is disposed and after that the children? And is the shell closed after the code in the handleEvent method has finished?

Comment: Controls are normally closed before they are disposed so you get a SWT.Close event before the dispose. So when the SWT.Dispose listener is called the Shell is closed but not yet disposed.

Comment: I'm sorry. I should not have written 'close'. My original question was: If the STW.Dispose event is fired, is the parent shell disposed right after the code ran in the corresponding handleEvent method or is it disposed in the moment, when the event was intercepted (and in the handleEvent method is IS now disposed)?

Comment: Normally it is the Shell which is disposed first. The first thing the Shell dispose does is send the SWT.Dispose for the shell, then the children of the shell are disposed and finally the Shell's resources are released and the shell is marked as disposed.

Comment: I understand! But your explanation means that at first, the children are disposed and after that the shell itself but in your answer you said it the other way around. Because of that I am a bit confused now :s

Comment: No, I said the SWT.Dispose for the Shell is sent first, followed by the dispose of the children, followed by releasing the shell resources and setting the disposed flag.